# How to overcome limitation of Snowflake Varchar (16,777,216) to load image data

Tags: json, image, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant, varcharmax

We have a scenario to load Image column from SQL Server which is our source and load into Snowflake, but its failing due to "String Long Issue" as Snowflake has Varchar Limitations.

Till now, we have tried Varchar and Variant datatypes as well to load this Image datatype but due to the huge size its failing for Variant as well (Snowflake is trying to read it as JSON , that's why we have tried variant as well).

Is there is any way to overcome this limitation of Varchar data type length in snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle that as unstructured data, which is a recently-released public preview.

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-launches-unstructured-data-support-in-public-preview/

This shows how to get started:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/unstructured-intro.html

If you try something and it's not working, you can update your question with the code you're trying and others can try to help out.